# If logic in Pandas, Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I've got a Pandas Dataframe from which I want to compare two columns and create a new column with a calculation based off the result of the comparison. Logic would be the following:

```
If df['column1']>df['column2'] :
   df['New column']=(df['column1']+df['column2'])
else :
   df['New column']=(df['column1']+df['column2']+1)
```

I am fairly new to Pandas and Python so I'm sure I'm getting the structure wrong. Could you guys point me in the right direction?

Comment: I suggest you to read about [boolean arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) as well. They work both with numpy and pandas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this should do your work. Although you can find such similar question on stackoverflow without starting new question. Anyways.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 2)), columns=list('AB'))

def get_new_col_val(row):
    if row['A'] > row['B']:
        return row['A'] + row['B']
    else:
        return row['A'] + row['B'] + 1

df['new_col'] = df.apply(get_new_col_val, axis=1)
```

This is the simplest approach but there can be other ways of getting this done.

Enjoy!!!

Comment: if you find this question similar to another question you have to flag the question as a duplicate question! if you have the right privileges

Answer (score 1):

You can go for numpy for much more freedom. If you have only one if else statement then use `np.where`. You can access numpy libarary from pandas using `pd.np` i.e

If you have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5],'col2':[1,3,4,5,2]})

df['where'] = pd.np.where(df['col1']>df['col2'], df['col1']+df['col2'], df['col1']+df['col2']+1)

   col1  col2  where
0     1     1      3
1     2     3      6
2     3     4      8
3     4     5     10
4     5     2      7

# Not exactly by much like 
#if df['col1']>df['col2']:
#    return df['col1']+df['col2']
#else:
#    return df['col1']+df['col2']+1
```

If you have more than one else much like if else ladder then go for `np.select`

```
m1 = df['col1']<df['col2']
m2 = df['col1']>df['col2']

df['select'] = pd.np.select([m1,m2], [df['col1']+df['col2'],0],  'equal')
#                           all conditions,   all executables, final else
   col1  col2  where select
0     1     1      3  equal
1     2     3      6      5
2     3     4      8      7
3     4     5     10      9
4     5     2      7      0

#Which is much like 
#if df['col1']< df['col2']:
#    return df['col1'] + df['col2']
#elif df['col1']>df['col2']:
#    return 0
#else
#   return 'equal'
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Numpy now and it's indeed much simpler. Thanks!