# Create a "directional" pandas pct_change function

Tags: python, pandas, math, percentage

I want to create a directional pandas pct_change function, so a negative number in a prior row, followed by a larger negative number in a subsequent row will result in a negative pct_change (instead of positive).

I have created the following function:
```

```
ef pct_change_directional(x):
    if x.shift() > 0.0:
        return x.pct_change() #compute normally if prior number > 0

elif x.shift() < 0.0 and x > x.shift:
    return abs(x.pct_change()) # make positive

elif x.shift() <0.0 and x < x.shift():
    return -x.pct_change() #make negative
else:
    return 0
```

```

However when I apply it to my pandas dataframe column like so:

`df['col_pct_change'] = pct_change_directional(df[col1])`

I get the following error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

any ideas how I can make this work?

Thanks!
CWE

Comment: this is can be solved by using multiple np.where...

Comment: how exactly @Wen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Wen said multiple where, not unlikely `np.select`

```
mask1 = df[col].shift() > 0.0
mask2 = ((df[col].shift() < 0.0) & (df[col] > df[col].shift())
mask3 = ((df[col].shift() < 0.0) & (df[col] < df[col].shift())

np.select([mask1, mask2, mask3],
          [df[col].pct_change(), abs(df[col].pct_change()),
           -df[col].pct_change()],
           0)
```

Much detail about select and where you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48004865/if-logic-in-pandas-python-3)